# Adding Umano's AndroidSlidingUpPanel as an Android Studio Library

Tags: android, compilation, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I've been at this for hours and I still can't get Umano's sliding up panel library to work in android studio ( https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel ).

I created a "Libraries" directory at the root of my project, copied the library sources inside, and added the following:

-settings.gradle : `include 'Libraries:AndroidSlidingUpPanel:library', ':MyProject'`

-project build.gradle : `compile project(':Libraries:AndroidSlidingUpPanel:library')`

I've tried everything, I can get it to compile but once I use the

```
</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

in a layout it fails to compile.

BTW If I don't downgrade my build.gradle's gradle path to .7 (was .8) , I get an error at compilation time.

I have maven setup as a dependency and the v4.13.0.0 support library listed as a dependency both in the library and my project.

I have looked everywhere, I cannot get an answer for this: can anyone provide a step by step guide to creating a project and including this as a library?

Thank

EDIT - To clarift:

If I do all of the above and downgrade my :

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+'
  }
```

to:

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
  }
```

I get the project to compile. However if I use the layout from the library:

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    >
```

I get the following error: error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix on the SlidingUpPanel layout node. This means the library did not, in fact, compile and include correctly. 
That is why I was asking for a step by step on addid this library to a new Android Studio project.

Comment: What are your compile errors?

Comment: If I get the library to compile, it gives me an error on building when parsing the SlidingUpPanel XML element in my layout.

Comment: If you don't include the actual complete error messages then it's really difficult to diagnose the problem. "It gives me an error" isn't helpful.

Comment: Sorry thought that was implied: 

Either I can get it to compile and it says Error parsing XML, unbound prefix on the library layout node (meaning the library didnt really compile and include correctly) or I can't get it to compile at all, giving me Gradle version errors if I don't downgrade the grade my project uses.

Comment: Can I see your build.gradle file as well? I'll add an answer for the version mismatch problems when you try to use v0.8 of the plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until Android Studio reaches 1.0, you'll have to update Android Studio, the Android Gradle plugin, and the version of Gradle you're using in lockstep. Once we hit 1.0 on Android Studio and the plugin, we'll have much better backward compatibility.

If you're using Android Studio 0.4.0 or later (which I'd strongly recommend; in fact it should be offering you an upgrade to at least 0.4.2), then you need to use v0.8 of the plugin:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+'
    }
}
```

This requires Gradle 1.10. You usually specify this in the **gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties file** with this line:

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip
```

The IDE should be checking version numbers and offering to update everything for you, but that mechanism isn't working quite right yet. It sometimes works, sometimes doesn't.

Comment: Do you mean that I should change the library's build.gradle to that (from .7) or the project's build.gradle ? 

Initially, it is .8 for the project, .7 for the library. If I compile with those values, I get the following build error : You are using Gradle version 1.10, which is not supported by the version of the Android Fradle plug-in the project is using. 

If I change the project's to .7, it works. Why can't I keep .8 for the project, .7 for the library? I'm on 0.4.3 by the way. 

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Oh, you need to use the same version of the plugin all-around. I can't think of a reason why it would make sense to mix-and-match.

Comment: Well there might still be some things I don't understand about Gradle. I gotta say th emove from eclipse/ADT has not been an easy one, I feel like Android Studio is, in a lot of ways, a downgrade.

As for using multiple version of gradle in a project, doesn't it seem normal that if a libray was built with a old version, I could mix and match ?